# iOS - App Files not deleted when app is deleted

Tags: ios, database, sqlite

We ran into strange behavior.

1. Install the app from test flight
2. App creates a local sqlite database in the NSDocumentDirectory
3. User deletes the app
4. User reinstalls the app again from test flight (newer version)
5. **App sees old database in the app**

This has happened several times.  And my understanding was that apps are supposed to delete everything with it once they are deleted.  Yet intermittently this happens.

Anyone seen this issue before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume this is caused by **iCloud backup and restore** functionality. If you don't set the exclude back-up key explicitly, the iOS will automatically back-up your files in the document directory. In your case, the previous database was backed-up in the iCloud and when you re-installed the app, the iCloud restored the database file. That's the reason why you are seeing the old data. If you don't need to back up your app's database file use the following code:

#### Swift 4:

```
do
{
    var resourceValues = URLResourceValues()
    resourceValues.isExcludedFromBackup = true
    try databaseURL.setResourceValues(resourceValues)
}
catch
{
   print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

#### Old Version Code

```
do
{
   // Database URL
   try databaseURL.setResourceValue(true, forKey:NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey)
}
catch let error as NSError
{
   print("Error excluding \(URL.lastPathComponent) from backup \(error)");
}
```

Reference: [How do I prevent files from being backed up to iCloud and iTunes?](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1719/_index.html)

Comment: Thank you very much.  I will do that.